# Native Hibernate query works very slow from the application but very fast when I run it directly from MySQL workbench

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

In my application I use native query to fetch data:

```
SELECT  
     time_month, 
     CCC.closing_strike_value AS closing_strike_value, 
     CC.opening_strike_value AS opening_strike_value, 
     C.closing_time AS closing_time, 
     C.max_ask AS max_ask, 
     C.max_bid AS max_bid, 
     C.max_point_value AS max_point_value, 
     C.max_strike_value AS max_strike_value, 
     C.min_ask AS min_ask, 
     C.min_bid AS min_bid, 
     C.min_point_value AS min_point_value, 
     C.min_strike_value AS min_strike_value, 
     C.opening_time AS opening_time, 
     C.option_name AS option_name, 
     C.opening_time AS id 
 FROM 
     (SELECT  
         DATE(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(opening_time / 1000), '%Y-%m-01')) AS time_month, 
             MAX(closing_time) AS closing_time, 
             MAX(max_ask) AS max_ask, 
             MAX(max_bid) AS max_bid, 
             MAX(max_point_value) AS max_point_value, 
             MAX(max_strike_value) AS max_strike_value, 
             MIN(min_ask) AS min_ask, 
             MIN(min_bid) AS min_bid, 
             MIN(min_point_value) AS min_point_value, 
             MIN(min_strike_value) AS min_strike_value, 
             MIN(opening_time) AS opening_time, 
             option_name 
     FROM 
         candle_option 
     WHERE 
         option_name LIKE CONCAT('%', :optionName, '%') 
             AND opening_time BETWEEN :from AND :to 
     GROUP BY DATE(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(opening_time / 1000), '%Y-%m-01'))) C 
         JOIN 
     candle_option CC ON CC.opening_time = C.opening_time 
         AND CC.option_name = C.option_name 
         JOIN 
     candle_option CCC ON CCC.closing_time = C.closing_time 
         AND CCC.option_name = C.option_name 
 ORDER BY C.opening_time
```

Every column listed in the first select statement corresponds to a field within the Entity which I retrieve.

This native query works fine and returns valid results. However, there is one crucial problem - it fetches results dramatically slow even on small amounts of data when used by hibernate. However, when I run this query directly (I use MySQL Workbench) results are returned very fast. For instance, if this query is executed by hibernate, It takes about about 1 minute to get results; if I run this query directly from MySQL Workbench, then it takes only 100 milliseconds. 
I wonder why is this happening and would appreciate any hint or help.
Thanks!

Comment: yes, but does it take the same amount of time to execute? and the rest of the Hibernate time is Hibernate doing stuff with the query itself? i.e look at your chosen JPA providers log. Other JPA providers simply let SQL to pass through without slowing it all down.

Comment: Could it be that some other entities are fetched eagerly? Turn on SQL logging and see if any other queries are run against your database.